# Can't get mmenu plug-in mhead sticky header to work

Tags: mmenu

I'm trying to use sticky header from mmenu plugin, but can't get it to work.

```
    <script src="./mmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="./mhead.js"></script>
    <script>
        Mmenu.configs.classNames.selected = "active";
        Mmenu.configs.offCanvas.page.selector = "#my-page";

        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                const menu = new Mmenu( "#my-menu", {
                    slidingSubmenus: false,
                    extensions: ["theme-dark"],
                    "iconbar": {
                      "use": true,
                      "top": [
                         "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-home'></i></a>",
                         "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-user'></i></a>"
                      ],
                      "bottom": [
                         "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></a>",
                         "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></a>",
                         "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-linkedin'></i></a>"
                      ]
                   },
                   "navbars": [
                      {
                         "position": "top",
                         "content": [
                            "searchfield"
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                });
            }
        );
        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                new mhead( "#my-header", {
                    pin: 100
                });
            }
        );
    </script>
```

when I run it, I keep getting index.html:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: mhead is not defined
at HTMLDocument.

Anyone has the experience this js plugin? https://www.mmenujs.com/mhead/tutorial.html
Everything works fine, except for the sticky header.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
new Mhead
```

(notice the capital M)